# Running 2 Monitors with a Laptop - Need advice on phantom monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have been trying to connect 2 monitors to my laptop (Samsung NP700Z7C-SO, Windows 7), but I cannot seem to get the set up correctly. One of my monitors is connected through HDMI, and the other through VGA. I am trying to get 3 screens going, but I can only get two going at a time. My laptop's Intel HD 4000 can definitely run three screens, but I think what is apparently limiting me is that my laptop has an lvds cable rather than and eDP cable.

I thought I could fix this by buying a USB-VGA adapter, hooking that up to my VGA monitor, hooking up the HDMI monitor, and going to the screen settings to run the three monitors. I got all three monitors to show up on the display, but the VGA monitor is still not displaying anything. It is essentially a phantom monitor on which I can move windows and files, but the monitor is not physically showing me anything. I can even make that phantom monitor my main display!

One thing that is confusing to me is that when I hook up the VGA adapter to a USB2.0 port (it was made for 3.0), the monitor will start displaying but at a reduced 800x600 resolution. When it goes back to USB3.0, it doesnt display anything even though it shows up in my settings.

If anyone has any tips on what to do or what hardware could help, I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Can you confirm that your USB 3.0 port functions properly (with a flash drive, etc). If it all works on your USB 2.0 port, there is no reason why it shouldn't work with your USB 3.0 port.

Comment: Yup, I have tried other pieces of hardware into my 3.0 ports and they have all worked. I'm actually using a keyboard right now through one of them.

Comment: @joejoe31b Sorry, I'm new to the site. Forgot to tag you!